# How can I use the output of KODAMA to predict unknown data points?

Tags: r, predictive-models, k-nearest-neighbour, knowledge-discovery

I can use KODAMA to create a model that classifies input data into two groups by setting the `W` vector to indicate the group and fix to a vector of all `TRUE`, `length = length(W)`.

[KODAMA](http://www.kodama-project.com/tutorial.html) produces a dissimilarity matrix, a vector with the cross-validated accuracies, a proximity matrix, and a matrix containing all the classifications obtained maximizing the cross-validation accuracy. I don't pretend to know what any of those things are. But the dissimilarity matrix can be used as input to `cmdscale` which produces `pc1` & `pc2` values that can be plotted to visualize the model.

I need to know how to take the output from KODAMA and use it as input to the `knn.predict` function (or some other function) to predict data as being either one group or the other.

What confuses me is that the input to `knn.predict` must be a `dist.matrix` containing all the model and predicted data. However if I include the predicted data in KODAMA it influences the model generation which I need to avoid. Once I create the model in KODAMA I'm not sure how to calculate the distance values to use in the dist.matrix for `knn.predict` or even if this is the correct method to use to predict the data.

Any advice and suggestions is appreciated.

Comment: Are you asking about how KODAMA works, or about how the code works? If you are asking for code help, that would be off-topic here, but would be on-topic on [SO] if you could add a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1217536).

Comment: I can write R code, that's not the issue, I just don't understand enough about the theory/statistical methods to know what to do to the output of `KODAMA` to make it into suitable input to `knn.predict`. So either an explanation of what `KODAMA`'s output is in relation to the inputs required by `knn.predict` or alternatively a description of the method to convert it would be most helpful. I can implement the method myself, but I need to know what it is. Which I thought was on-topic enough, but if I'm wrong I could switch to Stack Overflow.

Comment: No you're fine here. I thought you were asking about the methods, but it was sufficiently ambiguous that it was worth checking. I didn't vote to close or migrate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated the KODAMA R package. Now, a non-metric muldimensional scaling is implemented inside the KODAMA function. The output is "pp".

Inside the KODAMA package, there are function for cross-validation using PLS-DA and KNN but they must not be used on the dissimilarity matrix.

Here there is the link to the new publication on 
 [Bioinformatics](http://bioinformatics.oxfordjournals.org/content/early/2016/11/18/bioinformatics.btw705.abstract)